# How to connect the dev tools of Firefox Desktop with Firefox for Android?

Tags: android, firefox, browser, devtools

I'm trying to connect Firefox for Android to Firefox Desktop (on Ubuntu 19.04) thanks to the doc at MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/about:debugging

But I'm facing the version issue like "Note: If the version of Firefox on your remote device is more than one major version older than the version running on your computer, you may see a message like the following:..."

My versions are:

- Firefox Desktop : 72.0.1
- Firefox for Android : 68.4.1

And I could not find any more recent version for Android, nor an older for Desktop.

Firefox ESR 68 for Desktop does not have the new about:debugging support...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found an answer:

Download Firefox 68 ESR : https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/#product-desktop-esr

Lauch it, then in `about:config` set `devtools.aboutdebugging.new-enabled` to `true`

Now, versions are OK and about:debugging has the "Connect device" tab.

\o/